# how to reload leafletjs with html select and ajax load mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dictionary, leaflet

My problems: When leaflet load from select box and send data to Ajax once run okay, but another change select box map into lefleat  not reload or load new latitude and longitude...
please help me.

index.php
my code above:

```
 <script>
        var lat;
        var long;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#lunch1').on('change',function () {
                var city_id=$(this).val();

                if(city_id){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'city_lat_long_load.php',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data:'city_id='+city_id,
                        success:function (data) {

                            if(data.status == 'ok'){
                                lat=data.result.latitude;
                                long=data.result.longitude;
                                //$("#Latitude").val(lat);
                               // $("#Longitude").val(long);

                                $(function() {
                                    // use below if you want to specify the path for leaflet's images
                                    //L.Icon.Default.imagePath = '@Url.Content("~/Content/img/leaflet")';
                                    var curLocation = [lat, long];

                                    // use below if you have a model
                                    // var curLocation = [@Model.Location.Latitude, @Model.Location.Longitude];

                                    if (curLocation[0] == 0 && curLocation[1] == 0) {
                                        curLocation = [46.288491738996690, 38.081338348906720];
                                    }else{
                                       // map.destroy();

                                        //map = L.map('MapLocation').setView(curLocation, 12);
                                    }
                                    var map = L.map('MapLocation').setView(curLocation, 11);


                                    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                                        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                                    }).addTo(map);

                                    map.attributionControl.setPrefix(false);

                                    var marker = new L.marker(curLocation, {
                                        draggable: 'true'
                                    });

                                    marker.on('dragend', function(event) {
                                        var position = marker.getLatLng();
                                        marker.setLatLng(position, {
                                            draggable: 'true'
                                        }).bindPopup(position).update();
                                        $("#Latitude").val(position.lat);
                                        $("#Longitude").val(position.lng).keyup();

                                    });

                                    $("#Latitude, #Longitude").change(function() {
                                        var position = [parseInt($("#Latitude").val()), parseInt($("#Longitude").val())];
                                        marker.setLatLng(position, {
                                            draggable: 'true'
                                        }).bindPopup(position).update();
                                        map.panTo(position);

                                    });

                                    map.addLayer(marker);
                                    map.release();
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Problems: When change `lunch1` select box first change work, but another change map not loaded.

Comment: problems to jquery script

Comment: Somebody is helping me !?